# how to display data frame variable value in a string of another dataframe in r?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe column with variables taken from another table has been created in new dataframe column
with some text.

```
this is my df1 dataframe

coltext
------

df[df$ID=="1234",'Name'] bought the expensive product df[df$ID=="1234",'price']
df[df$ID=="231",'Name'] bought the leather product
df[df$ID=="4321",'Name'] bought the spareparts
df[df$ID=="4568",'Name'] bought the expensive product

my df dataframe has name ID and Prince

ID    Name   price
1234  Rick   333
4568  Jim    555
231   Rex    122
```

I want to print my df1 column coltext with variable values

like

```
1. Rick bought the expensive product 333
```

my code

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  
  print(df1[i,1])
}
```

but i'm getting same string without values

```
df[df$ID=="1234",'Name'] bought the expensive product df[df$ID=="1234",'price']
```

is there a way to use values in place of rcode in string

Comment: Try glue package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `glue` package.

- One more thing, either use " inside ' ' or ' inside "", but don't mix these.
- Use either

  - `df[df$ID=="1234","Name"] bought the expensive product df[df$ID=="1234","price"]`
  - OR
  - `df[df$ID=='1234','Name] bought the expensive product df[df$ID=='1234','price']`
  - but don't use
  - `df[df$ID=="1234",'Name'] bought the expensive product df[df$ID=="1234",'price']`

```r
library(glue)

df <- read.table(text = 'ID    Name   price
1234  Rick   333
4568  Jim    555
231   Rex    122', header = T)

glue('{df[df$ID=="1234","Name"]} bought the expensive product {df[df$ID=="1234", "price"]}')
#> Rick bought the expensive product 333
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>